# An Unique Constrained ID for a Good Login System Database Design?

Tags: mysql, database-design, authentication, ms-access-2010, primary-key

As I saw many of the Login System's Database got a field for a series of Constrained ID arranged, it rises me up the question for my Login System Database Design, is that necessary.

The problem is, assume there is a register system, when the user registers an account, the `account name` is already unique, as the system will warn you for unavailable `account name`, because they are repeated in the database. So do we need a constrained ID arrangement for each successful register? Even though it allows repeated `account name`, cant we just use the user's `ID card no.` as the unique field?

Or assume there is no register system, the admin allocate the account, we can still use their `ID card no.` as the unique field.

It is not like there will be search efficiency or well-organized data structure. We do not identity record by the arrangement, but the unique field. There will also be redundancy if there is already another Unique field.

So far my Login System requires the `MemberID` and `Password` to login, `MemberID` is the constrained ID arrangement allocated by the system, which makes me think should I let the user create their whole `account name` or `ID card no.` and remove the `MemberID`.

Did I misunderstand the usage of them? Or is there a reason for it? Did a good data design need such constrained unique ID ?

Comment: A table needs at least one key but it can have more than one. There's no reason why that can't include any or all of the things you have mentioned if that's what makes sense in your case.

Comment: @sqlvogel does that mean as long as the field is unique, it could be a primary key? Despite the key field being messy and dont have a pattern? like user self created ID. I just want to make the database as not redundant as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually we offer the account or user name as a convenience to our users. It is a lot easier for them to remember the account "JohnSmith" then a seemingly random set of digits. Generally, we hide such details as surrogate key values from the users -- they don't need to know it anyway. Let's face it, our job is to make the user's life easier. If that makes our job more difficult (and it usually does) then so be it. We are here for their benefit, not the other way round.

So by all means provide a constrained text identifier for the convenience of your users.

Comment: thanks, I think I will think about the most user friendly option now